# Jquery Ajax Each function returns double

Tags: php, jquery

I have a Jquery Function that basically retrieves a list of users from the data base and inserts the information into divs. The problem is that im getting double reults, this is my first time retrieving from the database, Ive only ever sent to the database.. Any Help will be Greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Heres the Jquery Code:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'data.php', 
        data: "", 
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function(rows) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                var row = rows[i];          
                var id = row[0];
                var name = row[1];
                var mobile = row[2];
                var address = row[3];
                var email = row[4];

                $.each(rows, function() {
                    $('#contain').append('<div id="name">' + '<span>' + name + '</span>' + '</div>' + '<div id="id">' + id + '</div>' + '<div id="mobile">' + mobile + '</div>' + '<div id="address">' + address + '</div>' + '<div id="email">' + email + '</div>');
                });
            } 
        } 
    });
});
```

and the PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Just FYI, you're doing a lot of unnecessary string concatenation

Comment: .. My bad, Please show me the errors of my ways.. love learning, so as much criticism as possible is welcome.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
$.each(rows, function (){
     $('#contain').append('<div id="name">'+'<span>'+name+'</span>'+'</div>'+'<div id="id">'+id+'</div>'+'<div id="mobile">'+mobile+'</div>'+'<div id="address">'+address+'</div>'+'<div id="email">'+email+'</div>');
});
```

you should do just

```
$('#contain').append('<div id="name"><span>'+name+'</span></div><div id="id">'+id+'</div><div id="mobile">'+mobile+'</div><div id="address">'+address+'</div><div id="email">'+email+'</div>');
```